# Tangent plane equation in the point of intersection with $\space y$-axis

Tags: analysis

I've encountered one tiny problem -  I have to find tangent plane equation of the function $\space f(x,y)=y^3 - \sqrt{1-x^2y^2} \space$ in the point where it intersects with $\space y$-axis. So $\space f(0,y) = y^3... \space$ and that's not exactly one point, how am I supposed to find an equation with this? Is it OK if I fix an $\space y_0 \space$ and then write the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** Function $f(x,y)$ will have the intersection point with $y$-axis in a point $P=(0, y_0, 0)$. In your case it will be the point $P=(0, 1, 0)$. Find now the tangent plane...

**Figure:**

[image]